# Issue with passing generic type

Tags: java, generics, types, gson

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
public class ResponseProcessorFactory {

    public static <T> ResponseProcessor<T> newResponseProcessor(){
        return new GsonResponseProcessor<T>();
    }    
}

public class GsonResponseProcessor<T> implements ResponseProcessor<T> {

    protected T response;
    protected TypeToken typeToken;

    public GsonResponseProcessor() {
        this.typeToken = new TypeToken<T>(){};
    }

    @Override
    public void parse(String jsonString) throws JSONException, IOException {
            response = GsonHelper.getGsonInstance().fromJson(jsonString, typeToken.getType());
    }

    public T getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
}


private void ResponseProcessor getResponseProcessor(){
       return ResponseProcessorFactory<List<String>>.newResponseProcessor();
}
```

Now, whenever I invoke `getResponseProcessor()`, it doesn't return me the response processor for `List<String>`. Rather, it returns the default response processor for `Object`.

I'm sure, I'm missing some concept regarding generic. Can someone explain in detail ?

**EDIT :**
The real usage is like this :

```
   public BaseRequestWithResponseProcessor<List<Dashboard>> getDashboards(Listener<List<Dashboard>> responseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        String url = mBaseUrl + "/dashboard";

        ResponseProcessor<List<Dashboard>> responseProcessor = ResponseProcessorFactory.newResponseProcessor();

        AuthInfo authInfo = getAuthInfo();
        BaseRequestWithResponseProcessor<List<Dashboard>> request = new BaseRequestWithResponseProcessor<List<Dashboard>>(
                Method.GET, url, authInfo, null, responseProcessor, responseListener, errorListener);
        return request;
    }
```

Comment: Where and how do you call `getResponseProcessor()`?

Comment: Are you not just missing the public class ResponseProcessorFactory<T> ?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime) (observing the generic type during runtime) the problem you are looking for?

Comment: @Smutje : I have added the actual usage. Please check.

Comment: @SME_Dev : I'm quite sure, that is specifically what the problem is. Though I want to be sure and get more insights on it.

Comment: No, you did not add the actual usage for `getResponseProcessor`, only for `newResponseProcessor()`.

Comment: `getResponseProcessor` was only a mock to explain my usage case.

Comment: So why do you write this? And by the way, why should `ResponseProcessor<List<Dashboard>> responseProcessor = ResponseProcessorFactory.newResponseProcessor();` return you a `ResponseProcessor<List<String>>`?

Comment: @Smutje : It's not unreasonable to assume the right kind of object would be returned. The right type for `T` in this case is actually chosen by type inference. It is however not possible to know what type this is inside the `newResponseProcessor` method.

Comment: @Lii OP confuses the method he claims to call, so I can't assume anything at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `GsonResponseProcessor` constructor [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) has happened and at runtime only one version of the method will exist with the type variable `T` converted to `Object`.

In Java only one version of generic methods and classes will exist, the type parameters only exist during compile-time and will be replaced by `Object` during run-time.

Type tokens must be constructed with a concrete type to capture the type information. This is the whole point with them, to capture type information at a place where the concrete type is known. The token can then be stored in variables and later be used to lookup objects or get hold of the type information with reflection.

The solution here is that the caller of `getResponseProcessor` who knows the concrete type creates the type token and passes it as a parameter. You could also pass in a `Class` object if that works in you situation. If you want to use generic classes as tokens however, as in your example with `List<Dashboard>` you will need a type token.

Something like this:

```
ResponseProcessor<List<String>> p = ResponseProcessorFactory.newResponseProcessor(new TypeToken<List<String>>() {});
```

Comment: Type erasure. Bang on !
This is the reason why my approach wasn't working.
Thanks man !

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the type erasure by passing in the class type as method parameter.

```
public class ResponseProcessorFactory {

    public static <T> ResponseProcessor<T> newResponseProcessor(Class<T> type){
        return new GsonResponseProcessor<T>(type);
    }    
}

public class GsonResponseProcessor<T> implements ResponseProcessor<T> {

    protected T response;
    protected TypeToken typeToken;

    public GsonResponseProcessor(Class<T> type) {
        this.typeToken = TypeToken.get(type);//depends on the API version

        //this.typeToken = new TypeToken<T>(type);
        //this.typeToken = TypeToken.of(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void parse(String jsonString) throws JSONException, IOException {
            response = GsonHelper.getGsonInstance().fromJson(jsonString, typeToken.getType());
    }

    public T getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this only work if the `type` parameter is a non-generic type. In gauravsapiens's example, with `List<Dashboard>`, you can only get the class object of the raw `List` type without the type parameter. You have to use a type token to capture the type parameter.

Comment: I know this work. Have tried it already. Was curious why the approach I was using didn't work. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the signature to the correct type, too?

```
private ResponseProcessor<List<String>> getResponseProcessor() {
    return ResponseProcessorFactory.newResponseProcessor();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it seems your actual usage does not reflect your problem as you nowhere cast to `ResponseProcessor<List<String>>`.